# How to show form errors in modal/popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I've this inside **form.html.erb**:

```
<%= form_for([@customer, @error], remote:true) do |f| %>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add New Error</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <% if @error.errors.any? %>
      <% @error.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          <%= msg %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <label>Note</label>
    <%= f.text_field :note %>

    <br>

    <label>Delay</label>
    <%= f.check_box :is_delay_error %>

    <br>

    <label>Delivery</label>
    <%= f.check_box :is_delivery_error %>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I managed to show the modal when I clicked a button inside the view using this AJAX (**admin_errors.js.erb**):

```
$(document).on('click', '.new_error_btn', function(event){
  var customer_id = $(this).attr('data-customer-id');

  $.ajax({
    url: location.origin + '/customers/' + customer_id + '/errors/popup',
    type: "POST" 
  });
});
```

My **routes.rb** file:

```
resources :customers do
    resources :admin_errors, path: 'errors' do
      post 'popup', on: :collection # to show popup inside errors index
      # example: /customers/:customer_id/errors/popup
    end
end
```

My **admin_errors_controller.rb** file:

```
    before_action :set_customer, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :popup]

    def create
        @error          = AdminError.new(error_params)
        @error.customer = @customer

        if @error.save
            @saved = true
        else
            @saved = false
            # here I need to show the errors inside form modal
        end
        respond_to :js
    end

    def popup
        @error      = AdminError.new
        respond_to :js
    end

    def set_customer
        @customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id])
    end
```

My **popup.js.erb** file:

```
$(".modal-content", "#add_new_error_modal").html("<%= j render('admin_errors/form') %>");
$("#add_new_error_modal").modal("toggle");
```

And lastly, my **create.js.erb** file:

```
var saved = <%= @saved %>;

if (saved == true) {
    $("#add_new_error_modal").modal("toggle");
} else {
    console.log("can't save");
}
```

I got problem to show the errors inside the form modal. The errors are showing correctly inside normal HTML form (using `new` action that rendered `form` partial inside it).

Because I've some validation rules inside the AdminError model, I really want to show the error messages inside the form modal when the record couldn't be saved.

What should I do now to show the error messages?

Answer (score 0):

This how I do it finally:

Controller:

```
def create
        @error          = AdminError.new(error_params)
        @error.customer = @customer

        if @error.save
            # i do something here
            respond_to :js # create.js.erb
        else
            @errors_messages = @error.errors[:base]
            respond_to do |format|
                format.js {
                    render  :template   => "admin_errors/create_failed.js.erb",
                            :layout     => false,
                            :locals     => {:errors_messages => @errors_messages}
                }
            end
        end

    end
```

**create_failed.js.erb**

```
// grab locals from the create action and convert to valid JS object
var errors = <%= errors_messages.to_json.html_safe %>;

// clear #form_errors div 
// very useful for second submit attemps when there are already error alerts 
// inside the div
$("#form_errors").empty();

// loop the error message
for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
    $("#form_errors").append("<div class='alert alert-danger'>" + errors[i] + "</div>");
};

// now the #form_errors div
$("#form_errors").show();
```

Model (**admin_error.rb**)

```
class AdminError < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :customer

    validate :has_note
    validate :at_least_one_type

    def at_least_one_type
      if self.is_delay_error == false && self.is_delivery_error == false
        errors[:base] << ("Please choose at least one error type")
      end
    end

    def has_note
        if self.note.blank?
            errors[:base] << ("Note can't be blank")
        end
    end
end
```

And the form where I populate the error messages:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div id="form_errors" style="display:none;">
        <!-- will be populated by the create_failed.js.erb file -->
    </div>
</div>
```